# Bind blob parameter in node-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I have an SQLite3 table with BLOB primary key (`id`):

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id BLOB PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100)
);
```

In javascript models, the primary key (`id`) is represented as a Javascript string (one HEX byte per character):

```
var item = { 
    id: "2202D1B511604790922E5A090C81E169",
    title: "foo"
}
```

When I run the query below, the `id` parameter gets bound as a string. But I need it to be bound as a BLOB.

```
db.run('INSERT INTO item (id, title) VALUES ($id, $title)', {
    $id: item.id,
    $title: item.title
});
```

To illustrate, the above code generates the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO item (id, title) VALUES ("2202D1B511604790922E5A090C81E169", "foo");
```

What I need is this:

```
INSERT INTO item (id, title) VALUES (X'2202D1B511604790922E5A090C81E169', "foo");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the string needs to be converted to a buffer:

```
db.run('INSERT INTO item (id, title) VALUES ($id, $title)', {
    $id: Buffer.from(item.id, 'hex'),
    $title: item.title
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the string as a blob:

```
INSERT INTO item(id, title) VALUES(CAST(id_string AS BLOB), 'foo');
```

Note also that the right way to quote strings in SQL is to use single quotes.

Comment: Strangely, this does absolutely nothing. Still inserted as a string.

Comment: db.run('INSERT INTO item (id, title) VALUES (CAST($id as BLOB), $title)', {
    $id: item.id,
    $title: item.title
});